# DB Schema Design for storing Test Results

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema

I am working on a project to view test results for different 15 subsystems . Each subsystem is more or less similar but requires different monitoring parameters to be tested . Each subsystem has ~300 different parameters and 20 -40 test cases. User can select one or more monitoring params from total params(300) per subsystem for a particular test case and there can be many test executions in a day .

For each test , execution monitoring params and test data is defined based on specific configuration and Software release from multiple config and SW release.

Also one additional complexity is that each test cases output test data set ( steps , images etc. ) are not similar and can be different .

Based on current understanding , we thought below DB schema :-

Test Session to test cases ( 1 : Many )

Test Session to Customer Config ( Many : 1 )

Test Session to SW Release (Many : 1)

Test Case to Test Images ( 1 : Many )

Test Session to Monitoring params ( 1 : 1)

Test Session to Subsystem Info ( Many : 1)

Since each test case is different do we consider 1 separate table for each test case or shall we consider NoSQL DB ?

Our requirement is that user shall be able to search / annotate different test results also ?

Any suggestions on the above ? Are we in right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is highly relational and normalized, it seems to me a relational database is easier for data retrieval and storage. (Not too familar with how NoSQL handles join though).

If you use a separate table for each test case, you should consider:

1. What if you have a new test case? Is it easy for you to add a table?
2. Should you use the same table if two test case have identical output data set? If so, what if one of them has more other data set in the future?

Another possible approach is to have a master test case table, and separate output test data set tables, i.e., something like

```
create test_case (
test_case_id bigint,
test_session bigint, // foreign key to test_session
test_date date,
...
);

create test_image (
image_id bigint
test_case_id bigint, // foreign key to test_case
...
);

create test_step (
step_id bigint 
test_step_id bigint, // foreign key to test_case
...
);
```

Personally I think this is beautiful, but may not be practically if a test has many data set, or there are many different data set format.

It is also possible to create a fat `test_case` table which has many spare columns to store all the output datasets (say `step1` to `step100`, `image1` to `image100`), ugly but sometimes effective. Note that some RDBMS have poor performance if the table has too many columns.

Comment: Thanks, updated data type